# How to override @Produces with a mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, cdi, java-ee-7

I have a class that produces an ElasticSearch client for to be used with @Inject

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public Client createClient() {
    return new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(IP, 9300));
}
```

I want to mock this client in my unit tests with something like the following

```
@Produces
@Mock
private Client client;
```

This results in a AmbiguousResolutionException because there are two providers for the same bean.

How do I prioritize my mock produced class for unit tests only?

---

From comments below, I made the following changes. I set a break point in the alternative but its not getting hit.

ElasticSearchProducer.java

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ElasticSearchProducer {

    public static final String IP = "10.9.215.28";

    private Client client;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        client = createClient();
    }

    protected Client createClient() {
        return new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(IP, 9300));
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

ElasticSearchProducerAlternative.java

```
@Alternative
@ApplicationScoped
public class ElasticSearchProducerAlternative extends ElasticSearchProducer {

    @Override
    public Client createClient() {
        return Mockito.mock(Client.class);
    }
}
```

test-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>com.walmart.platform.pv.cdi.ElasticSearchProducerAlternative</class>
    </alternatives>

</beans>
```

ArquillianTest.java

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public abstract class ArquillianTest {
    @Deployment(testable = true)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {


        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "quintessence.war")
                .addPackages(true, "com.w.platform");

        war.merge(ShrinkWrap.create(GenericArchive.class).as(ExplodedImporter.class)
                        .importDirectory("src/main/webapp").as(GenericArchive.class),
                "/", Filters.includeAll());

        war.addAsManifestResource("etc/conf/test/import.sql");
        war.addAsManifestResource("test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml");
        war.addAsWebInfResource("test-beans.xml", "beans.xml");
        war.addAsWebInfResource("test-resources.xml", "resources.xml");

        System.out.println(war.toString(true));
        return war;
    }
}
```

In my test the alternative class is not used

Answer (score 3):

You need to remember to always write testable code.  Suppose your class is written like this

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ESClient {
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public Client createClient() {
        return new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(IP, 9300));
    }
}
```

This works, but isn't very testable.  You may want to use a mock for unit tests, no active connection.  We can refactor this to be more testable.  Consider this alternative implementation:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ESClient {
    private Client client;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
         this.client = createClient();
    }
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public Client getClient() {
        return this.client;
    }
    protected Client createClient() {
        return new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(IP, 9300));
    }
}
```

Yes, it's a little more verbose, but your concerns are separated better.  You can then provide an alternative implementation in your tests

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Alternative
public class MockESClient extends ESClient {
    @Override
    protected Client createClient() {
        // return your mock here
    }
}
```

Now you just need to activate this alternative in your `beans.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I attempted the changes and encountered a problem. Can you please review the edits I made above.

Comment: This line doesn't look correct in your snippet, can you fix it? `WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war").addPackages(true, "test);`

Comment: Also, can you clarify what your runtime is?  Container + version?

Comment: I update that line of code, I'm trying to hide what some may see as sensitive information. The container is Tomee 1.7. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then don't include `com.wmt` ;-) can you drop a mail on the tomee dev list? This smells like a bug w/ OWB or TomEE's deployment mechanisms.